# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection

I am following [this tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/creating-tfrecord-files-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/) and doing a project on custom object-detection using tensorflow.

So when I tried to create TF record for the train images using the following command

`python3 generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=data/train_labels.csv --output_path=data/train.record`

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 23, in <module>
    flags = tf.app.flags
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app'
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 102):

try using `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf`

Answer (score 31):

Which Tensorflow version, are you using? If it is TF2.0 then you need to replace `tf.app.flags` with `tf.compat.v1.flags` [defined here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/flags) since it is no longer supported.

Comment: I am using TF 1.13.1

Comment: I'm getting similar error with tf.app.run(), but changing to tf.compat.v1.run() didn't help.

Comment: @Dimitri I had the same problem as you. Use @ThMore answer. Change `import tensorflow as tf` to `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf`. Don't change anything else (`tf.app.flags` and `tf.app.run` stays as is).

Comment: @Dimitri it's  `tf.compat.v1.app.run()`

Answer (score 3):

use absl if you don't want to downgrade tf.

```
from absl import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    app.run(main)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got similar error, then installed tensorflow 1.15 version and it worked with following warning.

WARNING:tensorflow:From generate_tfrecord.py:104: The name tf.app.run is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.app.run instead.

So, if you got this error try using tf.compat.v1.app.run instead of tf.app.run as stated in the warning from tensorflow.