# Error generating a .record file in TensorFlow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I was having one similar error and to fix it I used AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app' as a solution from [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58258003/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-app). Then I got the same kind of error for tf.app.run() for which I used tf.compat.v1.app.run(). Then I get the following error. Is it because of my tensorflow version?

```
(venv) Nandus-MacBook-Air:object_detection nandudharmapalan$ python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=images/train_labels.csv --image_dir=images/train --output_path=images/train.record
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 99, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/Users/nandudharmapalan/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/Users/nandudharmapalan/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/Users/nandudharmapalan/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 90, in main
    tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 45, in create_tf_example
    encoded_jpg = fid.read()
  File "/Users/nandudharmapalan/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 122, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/Users/nandudharmapalan/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 84, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: images/train/000000.jpg; No such file or directory
(venv) Nandus-MacBook-Air:object_detection nandudharmapalan$ python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=images/train_labels.csv --image_dir=images/train --output_path=images/train.record
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 99, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "/Users/nandudharmapalan/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/Users/nandudharmapalan/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/Users/nandudharmapalan/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 90, in main
    tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 45, in create_tf_example
    encoded_jpg = fid.read()
  File "/Users/nandudharmapalan/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 122, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/Users/nandudharmapalan/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 84, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: images/train/000000.jpg; No such file or directory
```

Comment: This error is quite clear: images/train/000000.jpg; No such file or directory

Comment: Yeah that one is. Do you know about the other ones

Comment: What other ones? You have the same error two times