# How could I solve the flags=tensorflow.app.flags error

Tags: python-3.7

```
import tensorflow as tf
flags = tf.app.flags
```

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58258003/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-app)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use: `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf`