# Handling "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app'" with out downgrading

Tags: python, tensorflow

The error mentioned in the title is happening due to the call

```
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS
```

There are multiple questions related to this:

[How could I solve the flags=tensorflow.app.flags error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60589116/how-could-i-solve-the-flags-tensorflow-app-flags-error)

[AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58258003/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-app)

It can be learned that it is error caused due to the change in Tensorflow version. But, I don't want to downgrade the Tensorflow version as mentioned in almost all answers since it is causing further error in the code I want to run.

The answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67999183/2700041) suggested the following solution

```
from absl import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    app.run(main)
```

But, it is not working.

Is there any way to modify mode without downgrading Tensorflow version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can still use version 1.x features without downgrading by adding below two lines to your code.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS
```