# Unable to import TensorFlow_hub, getting "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'flags'" message

Tags: python, tensorflow, bert-language-model

I am trying to import TensorFlow hub in my local jupyter notebook but unable to do so. I have created a local conda environment installed all packages. Current tf version: Tensorflow 2.0 and local tf hub version : tensorflow-hub 0.1.1. when I run the "import tensorflow_hub as hub" code i get the below error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-5c017171c13e> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow_hub as hub

~\Anaconda3\Anaconda33\envs\myPython\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\__init__.py in <module>
     23 from tensorflow_hub.estimator import LatestModuleExporter
     24 from tensorflow_hub.estimator import register_module_for_export
---> 25 from tensorflow_hub.feature_column import image_embedding_column
     26 from tensorflow_hub.feature_column import text_embedding_column
     27 from tensorflow_hub.image_util import get_expected_image_size

~\Anaconda3\Anaconda33\envs\myPython\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\feature_column.py in <module>
     23 import tensorflow as tf
     24 from tensorflow_hub import image_util
---> 25 from tensorflow_hub import module
     26 
     27 # TODO(b/73987364): It is not possible to extend feature columns without

~\Anaconda3\Anaconda33\envs\myPython\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\module.py in <module>
     21 import tensorflow as tf
     22 from tensorflow_hub import module_spec
---> 23 from tensorflow_hub import native_module
     24 from tensorflow_hub import tensor_info
     25 

~\Anaconda3\Anaconda33\envs\myPython\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\native_module.py in <module>
     24 import tensorflow as tf
     25 
---> 26 from tensorflow_hub import compressed_module_resolver
     27 from tensorflow_hub import module_def_pb2
     28 from tensorflow_hub import module_impl

~\Anaconda3\Anaconda33\envs\myPython\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\compressed_module_resolver.py in <module>
     33 import tensorflow as tf
     34 
---> 35 from tensorflow_hub import resolver
     36 
     37 

~\Anaconda3\Anaconda33\envs\myPython\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\resolver.py in <module>
     32 from tensorflow_hub import tf_utils
     33 
---> 34 FLAGS = tf.flags.FLAGS
     35 
     36 tf.flags.DEFINE_string(

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'flags'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'app'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58258003/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-app)

Answer (score 1):

Since `TensorFlow Hub's` initial support for `Tensorflow 2.0` started from `TensorFlow Hub 0.3.0 version`, the issue is in the version of `TensorFlow Hub`(0.1.1) you are using which only supports Tensorflow 1.x versions.

Upgrade your TensorFlow Hub to latest( 0.8.0 as of today) using below command.

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-hub
```

As you can see in the error log, the tensorflow hub internally trying to assign `FLAGS = tf.flags.FLAGS`.
In Tensorlow 2.x `tf.flags.FLAGS` has been moved to `tf.compat.flags.Flag`  which is not addressed in `Tensorflow Hub 0.1.1`.

Now in the latest Tensorflow Hub(0.8.0) they are using flags like below.

```
from absl import flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
```

Upgrading Tensorflow Hub should resolve your issue.